# how to get high humidity and low temperature in room

Tags: pressure, water, sun, air

I want to start mushroom farm for that I have to maintain high humidity and low temperature for that ,So i finding solution for how to get high humidity and low temperature at low cost.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a question about physics

Comment: This may be more suitable on an engineering forum. Rather than addressing the cause and nature of phenomenon, it discusses the application of concepts to solve a problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well my answer probably isn't the one you're looking after, it is also probably not the cheapest, but, the first thing that come into my mind would be about lowering the air pressure into your room. You'd need to make a hermetic room where you'd use air pump to lower the pressure in the location you chose and by doing so, you'd allow the water to maintain a gas form under lower temperature. That is quite an extreme method and I have no clue how that artificial atmosphere would affect the mushroom grow. I guess you could just keep the mushroom moist at all time with water vaporizer and use a air conditioning to keep room temperature low. In fact my first idea would only be useful in a situation where you need to grow mushroom that need humidity in a cold environment so I guess you should just do as I secondly said x)

Comment: Thanks for details, I also planing to do one thing by easy way compress the air outside the room and expand that compressed air in my room , so when air expands it will getting cool, let me know if you have any suggestion in my idea.